# Bounded or unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Let denote $A=\{x\in R^n : f(x)=0\}$ where $f:R^n\to R^m$ continuous mapping.
I proved that $A$ is a closed set. 
But what can we say about boundedness of $A$?

Comment: Try $\sin$, indeed, try $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Depends on the function, right? If you consider $f$ as a matrix, it is unbounded if $Ker(f)\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: The identically $0$ function has $A=\mathbb R^n.$

Answer (score 0):

In fact any closed set can be the zero set of $f$ in this context. (That gives you all kinds of examples where $A$ is not bounded.) Proof: Suppose $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ is closed. Then $g(x) = d(x,A)$ maps $\mathbb R^n$ continuously to $[0,\infty)$ and $\{x\in \mathbb R^n : g(x)=0\}=A.$ You can now define $f(x) = (g(x),0,\dots,0)$ for a continuous map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ such that $\{x\in \mathbb R^n : f(x)=0\}=A.$